# Why would executing "hg push" be failing as shown below?

Tags: proxy, repository, mercurial, push, bitbucket.org

My **hgrc** file contains the following information:

```
[auth]
default.prefix = bitbucket.org
default.username = stephen-paul-chappell
default.password = ******************************
default.schemes = http https
proxy.prefix = wsa-sn.pcci.edu
proxy.username = 116042
proxy.password = ********
proxy.schemes = http https
[http_proxy]
host = wsa-sn.pcci.edu:3128
user = 116042
passwd = ********
[paths]
default = https://bitbucket.org/stephen-paul-chappell/praecipuas-tournament
[ui]
username = Stephen Chappell <noctis.skytower@gmail.com>
```

The information that shows up on standard output is as follows:

```
C:\Users\Zero\PycharmProjects\praecipuas-tournament>hg push --verbose --debug --traceback
pushing to https://bitbucket.org/stephen-paul-chappell/praecipuas-tournament
using https://bitbucket.org/stephen-paul-chappell/praecipuas-tournament
proxying through http://wsa-sn.pcci.edu:3128
sending capabilities command
using auth.default.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
query 1; heads
sending batch command
using auth.default.* for authentication
searching for changes
taking quick initial sample
searching: 2 queries
query 2; still undecided: 3, sample size is: 3
sending known command
using auth.default.* for authentication
2 total queries
preparing listkeys for "phases"
sending listkeys command
using auth.default.* for authentication
checking for updated bookmarks
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
using auth.default.* for authentication
4 changesets found
list of changesets:
5af610089cb70bdfbd322cd07276c91641edde8f
78421d9083a7888f885e96b556512b5b69e177e8
5c30291d73e0527a763c72a457fc6b23d1810399
742f3c2666be853791f7186d061d35dac5678894
bundling: 1/4 changesets (25.00%)
bundling: 2/4 changesets (50.00%)
bundling: 3/4 changesets (75.00%)
bundling: 4/4 changesets (100.00%)
bundling: 1/4 manifests (25.00%)
bundling: 2/4 manifests (50.00%)
bundling: 3/4 manifests (75.00%)
bundling: 4/4 manifests (100.00%)
bundling: source/__init__.py 1/19 files (5.26%)
bundling: source/controller/__init__.py 2/19 files (10.53%)
bundling: source/controller/scheduler.py 3/19 files (15.79%)
bundling: source/main.py 4/19 files (21.05%)
bundling: source/model/__init__.py 5/19 files (26.32%)
bundling: source/model/alliance.py 6/19 files (31.58%)
bundling: source/model/asset.py 7/19 files (36.84%)
bundling: source/model/building.py 8/19 files (42.11%)
bundling: source/model/defense.py 9/19 files (47.37%)
bundling: source/model/facility.py 10/19 files (52.63%)
bundling: source/model/fleet.py 11/19 files (57.89%)
bundling: source/model/galaxy.py 12/19 files (63.16%)
bundling: source/model/messages.py 13/19 files (68.42%)
bundling: source/model/research.py 14/19 files (73.68%)
bundling: source/model/resources.py 15/19 files (78.95%)
bundling: source/model/shipyard.py 16/19 files (84.21%)
bundling: source/model/sphere.py 17/19 files (89.47%)
bundling: source/view/__init__.py 18/19 files (94.74%)
bundling: source/view/viewport.py 19/19 files (100.00%)
sending unbundle command
sending 7540 bytes
using auth.default.* for authentication
sending: 7/14 kb (50.00%)
sending: 7/14 kb (50.00%)
using auth.default.* for authentication
http auth: user stephen-paul-chappell, password ******************************
using auth.default.* for authentication
bitbucket.org certificate successfully verified
sending: 14/14 kb (100.00%)
sending: 14/14 kb (100.00%)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 160, in _runcatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 885, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 646, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 976, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 947, in checkargs
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 882, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 716, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5228, in push
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 236, in push
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 664, in _pushchangeset
  File "mercurial\wireproto.pyo", line 391, in unbundle
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 202, in _callpush
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 172, in _call
  File "mercurial\httppeer.pyo", line 119, in _callstream
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 437, in open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 550, in http_response
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 469, in error
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 409, in _call_chain
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 911, in http_error_401
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 453, in http_error_auth_reqed
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 889, in http_error_auth_reqed
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 464, in retry_http_basic_auth
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 431, in open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 449, in _open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 409, in _call_chain
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 372, in https_open
  File "mercurial\keepalive.pyo", line 255, in do_open
URLError: <urlopen error ''>
abort: error: ''

C:\Users\Zero\PycharmProjects\praecipuas-tournament>
```

I am not sure what is going wrong exactly or how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with your proxy:

```
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 911, in http_error_401
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 453, in http_error_auth_reqed
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 889, in http_error_auth_reqed
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 464, in retry_http_basic_auth
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 431, in open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 449, in _open
  File "urllib2.pyo", line 409, in _call_chain
  File "mercurial\url.pyo", line 372, in https_open
  File "mercurial\keepalive.pyo", line 255, in do_open
URLError: <urlopen error ''>
```

So this shows a the proxy throw a 401 asking for authentication, so HG tries again (`retry_http_basic_auth`), but after that it seems to fail. I'm assuming you need the proxy, but are you able to try from a host that does not need the proxy just to make sure your mecurial repo is sane?

Also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21577770/130352) covered something similar and traced it to an issue with their load balancer not handling the size of the HTTP headers, which might be something else to look at (i.e., is the proxy not handling the HTTP headers correctly?)

Comment: Unfortunately, all my internet connections are behind a proxy where I live, and there is no convenient way to rectify the situation. Thank you for your help though! I will talk to the proxy administrator to see if something can be done to fix the problem.